# getting value of next textarea nested in td tr jquery

Tags: jquery

Im going crazy trying to figure out how to get the value of the bottom textarea. Im new to jquery/javascript which Im sure is the problem, Ive tried for several hours to figure out a working code combo to retrieve it.

Im trying to collect the value of the bottom textarea of these two table rows when this first is changed. I can get the first textarea value fine when its changed but I need the value of the bottom one when the change is made to the top textarea. Once I can figure that out I need to write a function to get the top when the bottom is changed, Im sure I can figure out how to reverse the process once I get an initial solution.

The tableRow class and id names are not required Ive added those during the testing process.

ANY HELP WOULD BE GREATLY APPRECIATED.

//html

```
<tr class="years" id="yearStart">
    <td class="fieldlabel">Year Range Start</td>
    <td colspan="7" class="textareacontainer">
        <textarea class="multiedit-field" name="yearRangeStart-<?php echo $k->id; ?>">
        <?php echo $k->yearRangeStart; ?></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="years" id="yearEnd">
    <td class="fieldlabel">Year Range End</td>
    <td colspan="7" class="textareacontainer">
        <textarea class="multiedit-field" name="yearRangeEnd-<?php echo $k->id; ?>">
        <?php echo $k->yearRangeEnd; ?></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
```

//jquery

```
$("#yearStart textarea").live("change", function(){

yearStart = $(this).val();

yearEnd = $(this).next('tr.years').find('textarea').val();

$.post("http://localhost:8888/...",
{
yearStart: yearStart,
yearEnd: yearEnd
},
function(data,status){
alert("\nEnd: " + yearEnd + "\nStart: " + yearStart + "\nData: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
});
```

Comment: so what happens when you try this?

Comment: Also, posting a jsfiddle might be useful.

Comment: I get an undefined value for the yearEnd variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On this line:

```
 yearEnd = $(this).next('tr.years').find('textarea').val();
```

$(this) points to a textarea, not the tr.

Try:

```
yearEnd = $(this).closest('tr').next('tr.years').find('textarea').val();
```

Comment: OH MY GOD!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! YOU HAVE NO IDEA HOW LONG I WENT ON THAT ONE. THANK YOU SO MUCH